# Linker error when i use my static library in my console application

Tags: c++, c++17, static-libraries, glfw, glew

I has got errors in my static library when i use it in my application, however my static library build without any errors. Errors in linker in lib to application

---

**If I delete it up (includes) then there are no errors, but when i use library in console application in include error. Console application didn't see link libraries to my static library:**

[image]

---

**Errors in console application:**

[image]

---

[image: flowchart]

---

Best regards,

Roman S

P.S. - *and so sory for my English language!*

Comment: Please don't show images of text, copy-paste text *as text* into the question. And it's not linker errors you get, it's compiler errors which you get because the header files can't be found. Where are the file installed in your system? What settings have made in your project to add the correct header-file locations?

Comment: The errors have nothing to do with linking. You did not set your include path correctly.  If you added the include folder maybe your ***glew includes*** folder does not have a GL folder at the first level.

Comment: Thanks for critique.

Comment: libs in solution, in folder libs. In my lib, in additional include directories i add (i write only glew link path becouse another paths is similar to this) $(SolutionDir)libs\glew-2.1.0\include. In librarian, in additional library directories i add $(SolutionDir)libs\glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\x64. In additional dependencies i add glew32s.lib

Comment: in console application, in additional include directories i add $(SolutionDir)framework\includes. And add my librari in vs with right to project -> Add -> References -> select my library

Comment: library compile ok. but console application say
Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

Comment: That is telling you that `$(SolutionDir)libs\glew-2.1.0\include` is not set properly for your console application. Note that setting this for your custom static lib does not help. If the console application needs to use this header.

Comment: but library compile without any errors and path is right

Comment: same error for all linked libraries

Comment: Did you add the include path to all libraries and projects that need to access the header. Setting it as a reference does not help.

Comment: ok. if i use glew in my library and linked glew with my library i shoud link glew to my application? Because i think library is contains linked glew, right?

Comment: ok. thanks. its work. but i think it's crazy add to all project that use my library in solution path to glew (and other libraries)

Comment: can i optimize this?